# bool flag reset?

Tags: c++, boolean

```
while(true){
    bool flag;
    while(true){
        if (conditions) {
            flag=true; 
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, is the flag reset to false condition after it exits the inner while loop? It seems from the display of the console that it is still in true condition.

Comment: 1) What language is this? 2) There is no code anywhere in there to set `flag` to `false` under any conditions, unless you have some language that does such a thing. (C doesn't. C++ doesn't.)

Comment: c++ ...Thank you, I got it. But actually, when i try to use breakpoints for the first time before it enters the while loop, xcode tells me it is false. the bool flag.

Comment: xcode may say so, but the only portable way to always be sure a variable has a sensible value is to initialize it yourself.

Comment: Uninitialized local variables are undefined in C++, so you better do `bool flag=false;` or bad things will happen.

Comment: You already answered your question when you said it's true (from the console) so I do not get the point, do you expect a different behaviour?

Comment: Another question: will the bool flag remember its original value? i mean like after the flag is set to be true, and then redeclare the name, doe it Remember it to be true?

Comment: I think you're confusing two different questions: 1) Will the flag be false? 2) Did something set the flag to false?

Comment: yeah...the first one is. when i declare a bool flag, is it initialized to be false; 2nd: does it still remember its original value when bool flag is declared again in while loop?

Comment: 1st: No, unless explicitly initialized, a local bool variable will be _undefined_ (it may look like `false` when you look at it and `true` when you look away). 2nd: No, each iteration of the loop will _create_ a new variable out of the stack. The fact that it will likely occupy the same memory than its previous reincarnation may lead you to believe that it will keep the value, but there is no such guarantee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no "reset". There is no magic whatsoever. In fact, `flag` will not even be magically initialized to `false` for you, you'll have to do it yourself.

I think you're thinking of classic examples of scope and shadowing:

```
int a = 4;
//a is 4 here
{
    int a = 3;
    //a is 3 here
}
//a is 4 here
```

But there is no magic here, either. There are two different variables `a` *which happen to share a name*. `a` in the inner block refers to the second integer. If you could refer to the first integer, you'd be reading a completely different integer.

Here is some magic:

```
SomeClass x; //x's constructor is called
{
    SomeOtherClass y; //y's constructor is called
} //y's destructor is called
```

Since `y` is automatic, it gets destroyed at the end of its scope. (So did the second `a`, by the way, only there was no way to tell.) If it has a destructor, it will be called. If its destructor does something fancy such as "resetting some flag", you'll see the results. (Only not through `y`, which will be gone.)

The fact that the `{}` have no if/while/function/etc. attached to them is irrelevant.